# Fetch checkbox id and value attributes from jquery AJAX's success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am working on web application project with-JSP,JQUERY,AJAX,MYSQL and Servlet. I have table.jsp as below :

```
<form id="frm_table">
        Username : <input type="text" id="txt_name" name="txt_name">
        <a href="" id="a_details">Bring Details</a>
        <br>            
        <table id="importTable">

        </table>
    </form>
```

You enter a name in textbox and click on link 'Bring Details' to search in database(MYSQL) similar name and return them in a table (Eg. Neha will bring - 'Neha','Nehal','Sneha','Snehal', etc.). Each table row will have a checkbox. 
AJAX call looks for it looks like this(fetchTable.js):

```
$('#a_details').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $.trim($('#txt_name').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "tableservlet",
        data: {txt_name: name,
        //dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert("Error Occured");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#importTable').empty();
            var str = '<tr><td></td><td>Name</td><td>Username</td><td>Project</td></tr>';
            $.each(data.details, function () {
                str += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id=' + this['uname'] + ' value=' + this['uname'] + '></td>';
                str += '<td>' + this['fname'] + '</td>';
                str += '<td>' + this['lname'] + '</td>';
                str += '<td>' + this['uname'] + '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#importTable').append(str);
        }
    });
});
```

This successfully brings the table with checkbox for each row on table.jsp page. On selecting a checkbox, I have to populate a dropdown list which will contain projects assigned to that selected username. For this i need id attribute value of selected checkbox.

The problem is that I cannot fetch the selected checkbox's id into my javascript file(fetchTable.js). Without this id I cannot populate my dropdown list.

Please help.....Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: wrap your jquery script in `$(document).ready(function(){  //YOUR JQUERY CODE });`

Comment: Yes, it is jquery script is inside $(document).ready()....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: the listener for the checkbox change must be in the callback of the AJAX request (the success: function (data) {} is called the callback of the AJAX-request).

Do something like:

```
success: function (data) {
  $('#importTable').empty();
  var str = '<tr><td></td><td>Name</td><td>Username</td>td>Project</td></tr>';
  $.each(data.details, function () {
    str += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id=' + this['uname'] + ' value=' + this['uname'] + '></td>';
    str += '<td>' + this['fname'] + '</td>';
    str += '<td>' + this['lname'] + '</td>';
    str += '<td>' + this['uname'] + '</td></tr>';
  });
  $('#importTable').append(str);
  ListenCheckboxChange();
}
```

then:

```
function ListenCheckboxChange(){
   // set event listeners for checkbox change
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get dynamic appended checkboxes value on jquery's .on method

```js
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "change", function(){

 //you can get value from here     

   alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no alert message is seen when checkbox is checked or unchecked..is there any another way...